# Is there a vectorised version of `Filter` (or `purrr::keep`) in R?

Tags: r, vectorization, purrr

Filter seems slower than the vectorised version in the following example:

```r
u = rnorm(1000000)

system.time(u[u > 0])
# utilisateur     système      écoulé 
#       0.02        0.00        0.01 

system.time(Filter(\(x) x > 0, u))
# utilisateur     système      écoulé 
#       0.71        0.00        0.72
```

Is there a faster function than `Filter` in this case (`purrr::keep` is even slower)?

Comment: what is the issue with `u[u > 0]`

Comment: It's not pretty, since it repeats `u`

Comment: `system.time((\(x) x[x>0])(u))` ?

Comment: You could create a wrapper function `filterFun <- function(x) x[x>0]; filterFun(u)`

Comment: I want to create the function on the fly

Answer (score 2):

It is subjective, but `subset` seems to convey a better message and it is not that slow as compared to `Filter` in this case

```
> system.time(subset(u, u > 0))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.022   0.005   0.027
> system.time(Filter(\(x) x > 0, u))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.579   0.008   0.587
```

Or may also do

```
library(magrittr)
> system.time(u %>% `[`(. > 0))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.012   0.003   0.016
```

Comment: It repeats u, so it's not pretty enough

Comment: @Julien what about `{\(x) x[x > 0]}(u)`

Comment: A little better, but it still repeats the variable

Answer (score -1):

Note that if you really do want to collect the `> 0` realizations from a distribution, you could also take the absolute value of half of the original number of realizations:

```
system.time(rnorm(1000000))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.06    0.00    0.07 
system.time(abs(rnorm(500000)))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.03    0.00    0.03
```

Comment: That was just a toy example

Comment: `Note that if you really do want to collect the > 0 realizations from *a distribution*, you could also take the absolute value of half of the original number of realization".  [My emphasis]  This is not true in general.  It is only true if the distribution is symmetric about zero.